# How can I make Chrome browser notifications always expanded to their maximum possible height in an OS X environment?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, browser, notifications

I issue notifications on my website through the following javascript code:

```
  var theTitle = "This is the title"      

  var options = {
      type: type,
      contextMessage: contextMessage,
      body: theBody,
      requireInteraction: interaction_boolean,
      onclick: this.notificationClicked(),
      buttons: buttons,
      icon: icon_path,
      tag: notification_tag
  }

  var n = new Notification(theTitle,options);
```

And the notifications are displayed properly.

However, they are shortened and I'd prefer them to fully show the notification's content without the need for user interaction on dragging it's height (because this is possible, and since it is possible I'm wondering if I can do anything to solve the issue at code level or OS level).

Here are the screenshots related to the problem:

[image]

Any idea? Thank you for your help

Comment: As explained this this thread, messages are always truncated. In the OS notification center, you can view the whole thing. They recommend keeping messages at 30 characters. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46043348/display-web-push-notification-with-long-title-body-text-on-chrome-firefox-withou

Comment: Here's a guide on how they appear in different systems and their character limits: https://blog.pushowl.com/push-notification-best-practices-the-ideal-length/

Comment: @LisaCerilli This is truly saddening, to be honest. So even though I'm able to drag the height to fit-content there's simply no way I can spawn the notification in the same way? Not even by tweaking the OS X?

Comment: Web push notifications have a character limit that you cannot change: you can refer to [this table](https://blog.pushpad.xyz/2020/03/web-push-notifications-character-limit/) in order to know the number of characters allowed on the different platforms.